# Java access bridge- issue while using getAccessibleContextAt

Tags: java, java-access-bridge

In C#.net code, have been trying to use the interface- `getAccessibleContextAt` in the following manner.

1. For the Java application in concern, I identify the main windows-handle
2. I get the pointer for the application context and the vmid using `getAccessibleContextFromHWND`. These are non zero and `getAccessibleContextFromHWND` returns true.
3. With these values and mouse position (x,y) trying to fetch the context of the underlying control using the interface `getAccessibleContextAt`. This method returns true, but the pointer for the control is zero.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private void GetJavaElementDetails(IntPtr javaAppHandle, int x, int y)
{
    if (JABHelper.isJavaWindow(javaAppHandle)==1)
    {
        Int32 vmid;
        IntPtr appContextPointer, ctlContextPointer;
        bool result = JABHelper.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(javaAppHandle, out vmid, out appContextPointer);
        result = JABHelper.getAccessibleContextAt(vmid, appContextPointer, x, y, out ctlContextPointer);
        AccessibleContextInfo acinfo = new AccessibleContextInfo();
        IntPtr acinfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(new AccessibleContextInfo()));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(new AccessibleContextInfo(),acinfoPtr, true);

        if (JABHelper.getAccessibleContextInfo(vmid, ctlContextPointer, acinfoPtr))
        {
            acinfo = (AccessibleContextInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(acinfoPtr, typeof(AccessibleContextInfo));
        }
    }
}
```

Where JABHelper is just a wrapper around the different interfaces exposed by the WindowsAccessBridge.dll.

ctlContextPointer- always happen to be zero. Any resolution for this issue will be highly appreciated. Also please let me know if I am doing something wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

See this code on the [Oracle Forums](https://community.oracle.com/message/5463279).

Check if you are properly declaring required structures and functions and if other functions to get accessible context info are working.

Also, see the definition of `GetAccessibleContextAt()` in `AccessBridgeCalls.c` (from the JavaFerret sample):

```
BOOL GetAccessibleContextAt(long vmID, AccessibleContext acParent, 
                            jint x, jint y, AccessibleContext *ac)
```

This means that `WindowsAccessBridge.dll` is expecting a pointer to memory allocated by you so it will write into that memory. Instead of passing `IntPtr` object as last parameter, try this:

```
IntPtr retPtrForAC = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(new Int32()));
result = JABHelper.getAccessibleContextAt(vmid, appContextPointer, x, y, out retPtrForAC);
```

Also use try catch blocks to check for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

````
[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextAt(long vmID, IntPtr acParent, Int32 x, Int32 y, out IntPtr ac);```

[DllImport("WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll", SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr accessibleContext, IntPtr acInfo);

--get the control handle using below line of code
--Used @Deepak answer reference

IntPtr retPtrForAC = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(new Int32()));
JabApi.getAccessibleContextAt(vmID, CurrentPtr, Xcord, Ycord, out retPtrForAC);


--Now get the Accessible context from retPtrForAC
IntPtr acPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(new AccessibleContextInfo()));
JabApi.getAccessibleContextInfo(vmID, retPtrForAC, acPtr);
var accessibleContextInfo = (AccessibleContextInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(acPtr, typeof(AccessibleContextInfo));
````